# Consider the initial value problem $y'=y+x, y(0)=2$. Find the first $4$ terms of the Taylor series.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, initial-value-problems

I'm not sure I'm understanding the question quite right.

What I did is:
\begin{gather}
y'=x+y, \quad\quad  y'(0) = 0 + y(0) = 2\\
y''=1+y',\quad\quad  y''(0) = 1+y'(0) = 3\\
y'''=y'',\quad\quad  y'''(0) = y''(0) = 3\\
y''''=y''', \quad\quad y''''(0) = y'''(0) = 3\\
\end{gather}

Is this right or does it satisfy the question?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: is not possible to find the solution of the equation and after to find the taylor expresion of this solution?

Comment: the solution im think is $y(x)=-x-1-3e^x$ then use taylor saries

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $y$ is a (smooth) solution of $y'=x+y$ with initial condition $y(0)=2$. The [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of $y$ at the point $0$ (also called the Maclaurin series of $y$) is given by
$$y(x)=\frac{y(0)}{0!}(x-0)^{0}+\frac{y'(0)}{1!}(x-0)^{1}+\frac{y''(0)}{2!}(x-0)^{2}+\frac{y'''(0)}{3!}(x-0)^{3}+\ldots.$$
Hence with what you already computed, you can compute the first four terms of the expansion above. For example, the third term is given by
$$\frac{y''(0)}{2!}(x-0)^{2}=\frac{3}{2}x^{2}.$$
Note that you only need $y''''(0)$ for the fifth term.

Comment: @strugglingchemist Does this answer your question? If it does, please accept it. :-)